# Автоподнималка GlassFish 4.1 средствами monit. Проблема в получении PID

Tags: ubuntu, glassfish, monit, daemon

Что-то долго мучаюсь с организацией автоподнималки **GlassFish 4.1** как демона средствами **monit** (https://mmonit.com/monit/) на **Ubuntu 16.04**.

Что делаю:

1. Использую модификацию скрипта отсюда: https://gist.github.com/maji-KY/4215640 чтобы создавать **pid** файл для **monit**.
   Мой вариант метода start() представлен ниже.
2. Запускаю скрипт с параметром **start** и GlassFish реально хорошо поднимается, **pid-файл пишется**. (В скрипте производится демонизация GLassFish через утилиту **daemon**)

```
start() {
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    # Подозреваю, проблема здесь: я получаю pid утилиты daemon, а нужен pid процесса запускаемого в --command.
    daemon --user root --pidfile=${pidfile} --command="${ASADMIN} ${START_OP} ${DOMAIN_ARGS}"
    # В качестве возвращаемого значения - pid запускаемого процесса
    RETVAL=$?
    [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch ${lockfile} && cp ${pidfile} ${DOMAIN_DIR}/${domain}/config/pid
    # Выводим содержимое pid-файла
    cat ${pidfile}
    return $RETVAL
}
```

**Проблема:** проверка pid'а показала, что сам процесс, чей **pid** пишется в файл **умирает** после того как GlassFish наплодит потоки и успешно развернётся. В итоге, получается, что monit будет смотреть за тут же умирающим (а хуже - за ДРУГИМ существующим) процессом, и либо будет пытаться запустить GlassFish при живом работающем экземпляре либо не будет пытаться этого сделать при дохлом GlassFish'е, если pid присвоится другому процессу.

**Вопрос:** как получить корректный pid главного процесса GlassFish?

Рассмотрю любые альтернативы для демонизации, главное, чтобы у меня был корректный pid в pid-файле для мониторинга именно monit'ом.

Спасибо!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/699596/416190

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за наводку на https://askubuntu.com/a/700070/546491. Предложенный в обсуждении вариант работал так же, как и мой, но был более аккуратен и понятен.

В итоге, мне пришлось вытаскивать pid через egrep:

```
ps aux | egrep $NAME | egrep "$DOMAIN" | egrep -o $USER{1}[^0-9]+[0-9]+ | egrep -o [0-9]+ > $PIDFILE
```

В итоге, получился такой вот скрипт запуска (почти полностью повторяет решение из ссылки выше, но работает правильно):

```
#!/bin/sh

#================================================================
# Можно разместить в /etc/init.d/                               #
# Вариант запуска: sudo service glassfish start                 #
# Автоподнималка через rc: sudo update-rc.d glassfish defaults  #
#================================================================

### BEGIN INIT INFO
#
# Provides:     glassfish
# Required-Start:   $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Glassfish scipt (Non official)
# Description:  Start Glassfish domain as service.
#       Non official startup script by Bernhard Sumser.
#
### END INIT INFO

# Using the LSB functions to perform the operations
# NOT needed because no LSB functions used
#. /lib/lsb/init-functions
USER=root
DOMAIN=your.domain.com
BASE=/path/to/GlassFish_Server/bin
NAME=glassfish
DAEMON=${BASE}/asadmin
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

#PID file for the daemon
PIDFILE=/var/run/glassfish.pid

#If the DAEMON is not there, then exit
[ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0


do_start()
{
    $DAEMON start-domain $DOMAIN&
    # Wait for child to exit before continuing
    wait
    # Make file with last background PID
    ps aux | egrep $NAME | egrep "$DOMAIN" | egrep -o $USER{1}[^0-9]+[0-9]+ | egrep -o [0-9]+ > $PIDFILE
    #echo $! > $PIDFILE

    # Didn't work because the programm prints from the background. Without moving to the bg no $! can be outputed to file
    #(($DAEMON start-domain) & echo $! > $PIDFILE &)
}

do_stop()
{
    $DAEMON stop-domain $DOMAIN
    if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
        rm -f $PIDFILE
    fi
}

check_root()
{
    if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
        echo "You must be root to start, stop and restart $NAME."
        exit 4
    fi
}

check_process()
{
    # Check if the process is already running. Ignore grep line.
    result=`ps aux | grep /opt/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l`
}

case $1 in
    start)
        check_root
        check_process
        if [ "$result" = "1"  ]; then
            echo "$NAME is already running"
        else
            # Check if PID file exists and delete it
            if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
                rm -f $PIDFILE
            else
                do_start
            fi              
        fi
    ;;

    stop)
        check_root
        if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
            do_stop
        else
            echo "$NAME is not running"
        fi
    ;;

    restart)
        check_root
        echo "Restarting $NAME..."
        check_process
        if [ "$result" = "1"  ]; then
            do_stop
            echo "Starting $NAME..."
            do_start
        fi                  
    ;;

    status)
        if [ -e $PIDFILE ]; then
            echo "$NAME is running. PID $(cat $PIDFILE)"
        else
            echo "$NAME is not running"
        fi
    ;;


    *)
            # Show help
            echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|status|stop|restart}" >&2
            exit 3
    ;;
esac
```

Да, у него есть недостатки, но он работает именно так, как мне необходимо: он **пишет** не pid мёртвого процесса запуска, а **живой pid работающего процесса GlassFish**.